# An electromagnetic wave incident on a closed loop

Tags: emc, electromagnetic

Consider the following diagram : 
[image]

Both the electric and magnetic fields will induce a voltage in this circuit. In more details, the component of the electric field that is in the plane of the circuit, perpendicular to them and directed upward or downward is the component that will induce the voltage  and the component of the magnetic field that is perpendicular to the plane of the wire and directed into or out of the page is the component that will induce also the voltage. Therefore, from this diagram the component of the electric field that will induce the voltage is 10cos(3). For the magnetic field, according to the solution of this question, it states that the magnetic field is totally perpendicular to the plane of the circuit so all of it will contribute in the induction of the voltage due to the magnetic field and this magnetic field will be equal to 10/120*pi. My question is that not all the magnetic field is perpendicular to the plane of the circuit since the wave is titled by 30 degrees from the axis of the circuit and therefore the component that will contribute to the induction of the voltage ( normal component) will be 10cos(30)/120*pi ????

Comment: Consider a source Z of 377 and target of 100 and a wavelength of 300 cm what attenuation of  100mV/cm due you expect with forward and return paths cancelling. Also what is the impedance of each 10cm track? and where is ground?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an electromagnetic wave traveling in free space, the electric field is perpendicular to the magnetic field. If this diagram is drawn on paper, then the magnetic field is perpendicular to the paper (going into and out of the paper). The loop is in the plane of the paper. So the magnetic field is actually perpendicular to the loop.